# what is an injective trapdoor function?

Tags: one-way-function, trapdoor

The answer to [this question at Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10087/meaning-of-trapdoor-in-cryptography) is clear about what a trapdoor function is, but what makes a trapdoor function *"injective"*?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function ?

Comment: @K.G. - From the link you posted above, an injective function is one that preserves distinctness.  Following this, a injective trapdoor function must be a one-way function that is hard to invert (except when using secret key) and never maps elements of domain to the same element in the co-domain.  is this correct?

Comment: "and never maps" _different_ "elements of the domain to the same element in the co-domain". $\hspace{.77 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer - So if the trapdoor function was not injective we would have different elements mapping to the same elements in co-domain.  What is the advantage of an injective trapdoor function ? Shouldn't we make it harder for an adversary to guess what an element of co-domain maps to in the domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trapdoor one-way injection is a trapdoor one-way function such that two different elements

of a single domain are never mapped to the same element of the corresponding codomain.

By [Goldreich-Levin](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gl.pdf), if there exists an trapdoor one-way injection

then semantically secure public key encryption exists.